# How to transform a list into a string?

Tags: java, string, list

I have the list of strings

```
List<String> lst;
```

I need to transform that list into a string as follows:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("String 1");
lst.add("String 2");
lst.add("String 3");
```

The String I want to get is:

```
"String 1 + String 2 + String 3"
```

If

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("String 1");
```

then I just want `String 1`

If `lst.isEmpty()` then I want `""`.

Is it possible to do that in a flexible way and avoid writing multiple `if-else if`?

***UPD***: I'm on `Java 7`

Comment: [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html), or switch to Java 8, there are many options.

Comment: Didn't we solved this on SO already?

Comment: @MarounMaroun What would be a possible solution in Java 8?

Comment: @St.Antario it's explained in the dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you only want to use native Java (and don't want to use a third-party library like Apache), and desire 1.7, I don't really see a way around a simple for loop with an easy condition.

I'm not sure if this is "multiple `if-else-if`, but this seems fairly straight-forward:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("String 1");
lst.add("String 2");
lst.add("String 3");

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
int size = lst.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    output.append(lst.get(i));
    if (i < size - 1)
        output.append(" + ");
}

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's better to use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `+` operator. You'll note the difference when your list gets bigger.

Comment: I agree with @MarounMaroun.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks :) I've edit my answer to use `StringBuilder`

Comment: @OriLentz last note, the compile will optimize `lst.size()` in the loop body, don't worry about it. Moving it outside won't improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

**Will it do ?**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("String 1");
    list.add("String 2");
    list.add("String 3");

    StringBuilder convert = new StringBuilder();
    convert.append(list.isEmpty() ? "" : list.get(0));

    for(int i = 1 ; i < list.size() ; i ++ ) {
        convert.append(" + ").append(list.get(i)));
    }

    System.out.println(convert.toString());
}
```

Comment: Again, advise for [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `+`.

Comment: `convert.append(" + " + list.get(i))` this + should also be replaced by the StringBuilder functions
And `&& list.size() >= 1` is unnecessary.